# shtml file - css popup with contact form - php include - process and stay in popup

Tags: php, css, popup

i have a site with shtml extensions for ssi.  i have 2 popups using css, no J.  I have a form in the popup, the contents are a php include.  The php executes before initally loading the form.  but I can't figure out how to process the php without leaving the popup, or even the original page.

I am new to php - have VBscript experience.  But I am really a fishing guide, not a programmer.  becoming very obvious today.

Thank you for your help

```
    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="brochure_request_form"></a>
    <div class="popup">

      <h2>Request a brochure</h2>
<!--#include file="includes/bropopup.php" -->
      <a href="#close" class="close"></a>
       </div>

here is the include...

     <?php
      echo 'first php done<br>';
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
              echo 'php executed';
          ?>
      <form name="frm_brochure_request" action="phptest.shtml" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="first name" />
      </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="request brochure">
      </form>
      <?php
      }
      else {
          echo 'submitted <br />';

      }?>
```

Here is most of the css - I am using this from an online demo.  the demo didn't include any form functionality, however.

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}
.overlay:target+.popup {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.close {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: -15px;
    width: 30px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(64, 128, 128, 0.8);
}
.popup p, .popup div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.popup label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 120px;
}
.popup input[type="text"], .popup input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #999 #ccc #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -ms-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.popup input[type="text"]:hover, .popup input[type="password"]:hover {
    border-color: #555 #888 #888;
}
```